# Wordpress install on root folder and on subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have to install a new Wordpress on a server, that already contains a Wordpress install on the root directory (/).
From now, I installed the new one in a /dev/ subdirectory. myserver.com/dev/ works fine and display the right front page.

But the other pages (like About, Contact, etc.) don't. About (myserver.com/dev/page-about/) just displays the 404 from the root install. Contact page myserver.com/dev/page-contact/ redirects to myserver.com/page-about/.

Here's the .htaccess on /dev/ :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The root install doesn't have a .htaccess... 
I also checked the permalinks settings, i use permalinks by postname, and it's ok.
The db is clean and imported from a local install (i did search and replace on the sql dump to switch to the correct domain).
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try change the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**RewriteBase /dev/** is localhost purpose

Comment: Well, that doesn't change anything... I also put a htaccess on root install, same. I'm gonna put the dev install on one of my personal server, I think the problem comes from their root install / server conf...

Answer (score -1):

It has no concern with the .htacess, try instead editing your menu that created on myserver.com/dev/ has custom URLs which are doing this. Correct the menu and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: The menu and its URL are right, that's not the problem I mentionned.

Comment: please give the exact URL of website having problem, i have visited myserver.com/dev but it has no about us or contact us.

Comment: ... it's just an example URL ... There's no need to see the website to help me (anyway i can't give it).

Comment: And i am very much sure that it is not the issue of .htaccess

Comment: Lets discuss more about it, we can solve this issue. It has no concern with SQL also, it can be a issue while installing WordPress. Can you reinstal at myserver.com/dev

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43933/discussion-between-enguerranws-and-waseem-abbas)